# Null content Shared Preferences in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an app that uses Shared Preferences, so I created a class only for this, but when I launch the app I get this error:

```
2020-06-03 14:51:50.124 32656-32656/com.go.experimental E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.go.experimental, PID: 32656
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.go.experimental/com.go.experimental.AccesoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:184)
    at com.go.experimental.tools.Preferences.<init>(Preferences.kt:39)
    at com.go.experimental.AccesoActivity.<init>(AccesoActivity.kt:26)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it's my first Kotlin app so I hope you can help me see my mistake.

Here's my Shared Preferences class:

```
class Preferences(context: Context) {

  private val SHARED_PREFS = "GO_SHARED_PREFS"
  private val ID = "id"
  private val NAME = "name"
  private val PHONE = "phone"

  private var prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0)

  var id: Int
    get() = prefs!!.getInt(ID.toString(), 0)
    set(value) = prefs!!.edit().putInt(ID, value).apply()

  var name: String?
    get() = prefs!!.getString(NAME, "")
    set(value) = prefs!!.edit().putString(NAME, value).apply()

  var phone: Int
    get() = prefs!!.getInt(PHONE, 0)
    set(value) = prefs!!.edit().putInt(PHONE, value).apply()
```

And here is how I use it on my Activity:

```
var prefs = Preferences(this@AccesoActivity)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acceso)

    tvTipoCodigo = findViewById(R.id.tv_tipo_acceso)
    tvNumeroTelefono = findViewById(R.id.tv_guest_number)
    tvCodigoNumerico = findViewById(R.id.tv_numeric_code)
    tvFecha = findViewById(R.id.et_activation_code)
    imCodigoQR = findViewById(R.id.iv_qr_code)

    codigoNumerico = generateNumericalNumber()

    saveCode()
}

private fun saveCode(){
    var name: String? = prefs.name
    var phone: Long? = prefs.phone
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question to include the complete stack trace and the complete function where you are using `Preferences`.

Comment: I edited the question. :)

Comment: OK... we still could use the stack trace. What you have seems like it should be OK, if `generateCode()` is the only place you use `Preferences`, and `onCreate()` is the only place that you use `generateCode()`. I am hoping(?) that the complete stack trace will point out something else.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, it's the only place I use both methods. `onCreate()` is the Activity method

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the image of the stack trace AccesoActiviy = MainActivity

Comment: Stack traces are text, and it is *much* better to post them as text rather than images. You can copy and paste from the Logcat window. Note that your stack trace does not match your code. Beyond the name difference, you are creating a `Preferences` instance as part of initialization of `AccesoActivity`, not from a call to `generateCode()` in `onCreate()`. We need the code and the stack trace to match. Providing us code that is not what is crashing does neither you nor us any good.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought I could fix it but I have the same mistake. I edited the question with full code and stack trace

Answer (score 2):

```
var prefs = Preferences(this@AccesoActivity)
```

This is not going to work. Never try to use an `Activity` object until after `super.onCreate()`, except in very specific situations.

Switch this to:

```
lateinit var prefs: Preferences
```

and add this to `onCreate()` after `super.onCreate()`:

```
prefs = Preferences(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

CommonsWare is completely right. You also can use `lazy` delegate. It adds a little overhead but it's easier to read at least from my point of view

```kotlin
val prefs by lazy { Preferences(this) }
```