# android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference id DBhandler

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I was trying to create an android app in Kotlin, which use prepopulated database
I have some structure (2 activities with recyclerview and adapter, one of the activities (this which isn't main) and adapters use dbHandler to get data from Database) and a database helper, created with help of
this tutorial https://medium.com/@johann.pardanaud/ship-an-android-app-with-a-pre-populated-database-cd2b3aa3311f
But after I tried to launch the activity with dbHelper my app crushed and i get the followin error: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`
It points to this line in my dbHandler code:

```kotlin
 private val preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
        "${context.packageName}.database_versions",
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    )
```

It also reffer to this where dbHandler was called and it's (not surprisingly) this line in activity I launched:

```kotlin
val dbHandler = LegoDBhandler(this, null, null, 1)
```

It was the very first line of the activity.

The creator (or maybe I should rather say declaration) of dbHelper class is the followint line:

```kotlin
public class LegoDBhandler(var context: Context, name: String?, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION)
```

And as far as I know if the variable isn't declared with an `?` at the end it can't even be assigned as null so what could cause that error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null content Shared Preferences in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173450/null-content-shared-preferences-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is

> It was the very first line of the activity

In this moment activity not really created and this is why context = null. Try to move `LegoDBhandler` creation to activity `onCreate` method

Comment: Well that is some solution but the problem is that this way it wouldn't be accesible in other functions - which sometimes is really necessery. 
Well I could declare it in any function that use it, but that seem way to over the top. 
I thought about declate it as `var dbHandler? = null` at the beginning of an activity and then in oncreate method do the real assigment: `this.dbHandler = LegoDBhandler(this, null, null, 1)`... but Android studio just shows me the message `Property getter or setter expected`. I even try add it manually but still get the same message...

Comment: You should specify type of dbHandler explicitly like this ```private var dbHandler: LegoDBhandler? = null``` and initialize it in onCreate method ```dbHandler = LegoDBhandler(this, null, null, 1)```. Another solution is declare dbHandler as ```private lateinit var dbHandler: LegoDBhandler```